# [rtl8723be]Windows 10 gives 15Mbps download speed while Ubuntu 15.10 gives 5 Mbps

Tags: download-speed, rtl8723be

I am running a dualboot setup on my Lenovo Flex2 with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10. I am on the rtlwifi - rtl8723be wireless card.
While my wifi disconnect issue has been resolved, I have found out that my wifi speed is 3 times less than what I get on Windows 10.

I have a 15 Mbps broadband connection. I consistently get the same speed of 15 mbps on windows but a maximum of 5 Mbps on Ubuntu. On my Android phone I get around 12 to 13.5 Mbps.

I am on channel 6 (2437MHz) of the wifi router with AES encryption .Router is Tenda_3623D8. Current connection of my Ubuntu machine is on the 40M bandwidth as per the router status page.

Any idea how to reach a better speed on Ubuntu?

Comment: See if wifi module has power saving feature. You might consider disabling it if it exists

Comment: **On side note:** One should do apples to apples comparison...comparing your laptop/desktop with Smart phone(even based on Android) is not a good idea...my smart phone has always better performance than laptop/desktop for the same wifi.

Comment: @Ashu,  i dont think that is entirely true.  the download speed should not vary too much between devices.  having said that I have already compared windows vs ubuntu on the same laptop